# Woocommerce two columns for product attributes (Left and right eye)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, e-commerce

i'm working on a woocommerce website for eye lens.
is there any way to make attributs selection like the captures ?
user must chose options for left and right eye or if he check the checkbox he can chose one values for boths eys
thank you
[image]
[image]

i tired to find the solutions but i need your help

Comment: With simple js toggle you can hide unneeded fields and update the title of the option. You will need to use  Woo JS event **found_variation** to pass the "hidden options" otherwise if its required will return error. Also depends how you config your prices. Do all variations have same price ? Do all variation have same quantities ? Then pass all params on adding_to_cart event.

Comment: thank you for your attention, but first i need to make 2 columns of attributes, one for left eye and the other for the right eye. Yes all variations have same price and quantity.